# Implementing an image upload button using Jython & Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser, jython-2.7

I'm developing a cross platform desktop application using Jython and Swing, and I found a hitch.
I would like to develop a button that allows me to load an image in its background and to change it when I reclick on the image loaded.

I attach as an example some pictures on how I would like my widget to be.

[Upload pane without image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEo65.png)

And then, when I load an image:

[Upload Pane with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHwoQ.png)

I tried with the following code:

```
fd = FileDialog(self, "Scegli un'immagine", FileDialog.LOAD)
fd.setFile(';*.'.join(("*.bmp","jpg","jpeg","wbmp","png","gif")))
fd.setVisible(True)
fileName = fd.getFile()
if fileName != None :
    fileAbsPath = os.path.abspath(fileName)
    """'self.bigDict['imgButton']' is the current JButton"""
    self.bigDict['imgButton'].setIcon(ImageIcon(fileAbsPath))
```

When I click on "Open", the image is not inserted into the button. I do not understand why.
I also tried with the following code:

```
if fileName != None :
    fileAbsPath = os.path.abspath(fileName)
    img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(fileAbsPath))
    self.bigDict['imgButton'].setIcon(img)
```

In the above example the following error is reported:

> img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(fileAbsPath)) 
>   TypeError: getClass(): expected 1 args; got 0

I would be curious to know why the button is not updated with the image loaded, and why the above error in java would not happen.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start trying then. We help on your way. We don't draw the whole map for you, or do the coding work for your vision.

Comment: You are definitely right. I edited to make people understand what I've done so far.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I correct again or is it okay now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is very simple. 
When an image is loaded with *FileDialog* it is "virtually located" in the FileDialog window, but the image does not exist. I realized this when I tried to copy the image from the absolute path to the destination folder, using `shutil.copy2(self.imgAbsPath, destinationPath+'/'+self.imgName)`, which reported an error message indicating that the image does not exist.
To provide the concrete path of a file, it is necessary to add information about the folder where it is located. 
In practice you have to create the **relative path**, before generating the absolute one:

```
fd = FileDialog(self, "Scegli un'immagine", FileDialog.LOAD)
fd.setFile(';*.'.join(("*.bmp","jpg","jpeg","wbmp","png","gif")))
fd.setVisible(True)
self.imgName = fd.getFile()
relativePath = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile() """Here is the missing piece!"""
if self.imgName != None:
   self.imgAbsPath = os.path.abspath(relativePath) """Here the absolute path is correctly obtained!"""
   self.bigDict['imgButton'].setIcon(ImageIcon(ImageIcon(self.imgAbsPath).getImage().getScaledInstance(130, 130, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)))
   """The image, before being inserted into the button, is slightly resized, to avoid graphic bumps!"""
```

I hope I've been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

getClass() needs 1 argument: the implicit `this` argument. You must call the method on an object, or use the MyClass.class notation.

Comment: I am pleased to note that when I load the frame at the opening of the app, the image is loaded (using `browseBtn = JButton(ImageIcon('img/dEo65.png'), actionPerformed = ontology['browseImg'])`, so i discarded the `img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(fileAbsPath))` option), while I update instead I can not see any image. I also tried reloading not only the button, but also the JPanel that contained the button...!
In the various attempts I also tried to empty the JPanel to add a new button but nothing...